# How Change A Label's Text In A Timer's Tick (GUI Is Busy)

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, timer, backgroundworker, windows

i have a strange situation.
please see the `backgroundWorker5_RunWorkerCompleted` event:

```
    private void backgroundWorker5_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnStartAdventures.Text = "Start Adventure";
        btnStartAdventures.Enabled = true;

        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
            return;
        }
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            lblStatusValueInAdventures.Text = "Cancelled...";
        }
        else
        {
            lblStatusValueInAdventures.Text = "Completed";
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
            // MessageBox.Show("start timer");
            Thread.Sleep((int.Parse(txtDelayInAdventures.Text)) * 60000);
            //MessageBox.Show("end timer");
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Stop();
            lblTimer.Text = "0";
            btnStartAdventures.PerformClick();
        }
    }
```

and that Timer is :

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { lblTimer.Text = (int.Parse(lblTimer.Text) + 1).ToString(); }));
}
```

but this timer can not change `lblTimer's Text`.
how can i fix this problem?

**EDIT:**
that Thread.Sleep is necessary and i can not remove it.
i want a loop that never ends and those codes are for that.

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "a loop that never ends"? A Thread.Sleep on the UI thread (RunWorkerCompleted event executes on the UI thread) will effectively freeze the UI thread, which means that no interaction with the UI thread will be shown.

Comment: uuuuuuummmmmmmmm so what is your suggestion. what can i do about that?

Comment: hey man please put your comment as my answer.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? As far as I can guess, you are doing some work in a background thread - backgroundWorker5 - (the UI thread is responsive). When backgroundWorker5 is finished you want to start a timer and display a counter in a label while the UI is still responsive (for somebody to stop the timer maybe?). Something like that?

Comment: yes you are right.  i want a loop and it never stops until a user click cancel button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested;

What do you mean by "a loop that never ends"? A `Thread.Sleep` on the UI thread (RunWorkerCompleted event executes on the UI thread) will effectively freeze the UI thread, which means that no interaction with the UI thread will be shown.

Comments:

> What are you trying to achieve? As far as I can guess, you are doing
>   some work in a background thread - backgroundWorker5 - (the UI thread
>   is responsive). When backgroundWorker5 is finished you want to start a
>   timer and display a counter in a label while the UI is still
>   responsive (for somebody to stop the timer maybe?). Something like
>   that? – Mario 3 mins ago edit
>
> yes you are right. i want a loop and it never stops until a user click
>   cancel button. – MoonLight 1 min ago

So, try something like this:

```
int time = 0;

private void backgroundWorker5_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    btnStartAdventures.Text = "Start Adventure";
    btnStartAdventures.Enabled = true;

    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        return;
    }
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        lblStatusValueInAdventures.Text = "Cancelled...";
    }
    else
    {
        lblStatusValueInAdventures.Text = "Completed";
        timer1.Interval = 1000; //<--- Tick each second, you can change this.
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
        // MessageBox.Show("start timer");
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblTimer.Text = (time + 1).ToString();
}

private void button_Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //MessageBox.Show("end timer");
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    timer1.Stop();
    lblTimer.Text = "0";
    btnStartAdventures.PerformClick();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Thread.Sleep
> ```

There's your problem.

Never call `Thread.Sleep` in a UI thread; it will freeze the UI.

Get rid of that, and it will work fine.

You can put the rest of the work in the timer callback.

You can also use C# 5 async to make this much simpler.

Comment: thanks man, please see my edit.  how can i replace that Thread.Sleep with Timer?

Answer (score 1):

You have to refresh item.

```
lblTimer.Refresh()
```

and also you could refresh form

```
frmName.Refresh();
```

and make thread to sleep 0 milliseconds that gives space for other processes.

Comment: also my form Name is MainForm and there is no Refresh() method for that!